# jquery form validator (checkbox group)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

in documentation, i have this for validate checkgroup

[documentatiion method](http://formvalidator.net/#default-validators_checkboxgroup)

is there a way for use different method by the group name ? (parent div ? may be)

normal way :

```
input name="newsletters[]" data-validation="checkbox_group" data-validation-qty="min1" type="checkbox">
```

my problem :

I have a different name for each checkbox (but the same group)

ty

Comment: Could be this `^(?:[1-9][0-9]{2,3}|[5-9][0-9])00$`

Answer (score 0):

Try Set the name of group to atribute name and put the values in data-value. For example:

```
    @for(int i=0;i<newsletters.Length;i++) {
      <input name="GroupName" data-value="newsletters[i]" data-validation="checkbox_group" data-validation-qty="min1" type="checkbox" />
    }
```

Hope help you